# Placing a regex match inside div id after using anyorigin.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am looking to create a simple track parcel script for my website, so far I have managed to get the code from another site using anyorigin.com. But now I am having trouble fitting the code together so it works. My aim is to regex match a certain pattern 'patt1' from the string 'var str' and then place this inside the div #output. Heres the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var origin = 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=';
var site = 'app3.hongkongpost.com/CGI/mt/genresult.jsp?tracknbr=RB444639739HK';
var call = '&callback=?';

function myFunction(){$.getJSON(origin + site + call);}

var str= myFunction;
var patt1=/the item \(([^\)]+)\) left Hong Kong for its destination on \d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}/i;
var result = str.match(patt1);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = patt1.exec(str);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is still not working =(

Comment: :(:( then i should say, you have problem with your str variable. you need to check(using alert or some sort of javascript things) whether it has the desired content or not. you can show us that too.

Answer (score 0):

Whole javascript

```
var origin = 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=';
var site = 'app3.hongkongpost.com/CGI/mt/genresult.jsp?tracknbr=RB444639739HK';
var call = '&callback=?';

function myFunction(pattern){
    $.get(origin + site + call, function(resp) {
        $("#output").html(resp.match(pattern)[0]);
    });
}
var patt1 = /the item \([^\)]+\) left Hong Kong for its destination on \d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}/i;
var result = myFunction(patt1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I tried a jsfiddle of this and it didnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/veNKp/1/